# Data not saving in database using C# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a project that used to work fine last time I worked on it, but after I formatted the PC the program couldn't find the database, the solution I found was to use this :

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|PAPPloran.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Instead having the full path for the database file location.

That was the change that might be causing my problem, data isn't being saved on database anymore, it is shown on  a datagridview on program after I "save" but when I close and reopen the program isn't there anymore.

Example from my program of a save button:

```
private void fusionButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "" & dateTimePicker1.Text != "" & textBox3.Text != "" & textBox4.Text != "" & textBox5.Text != "" & comboBox2.Text != "" & textBox7.Text != "" & textBox8.Text != "" & textBox9.Text != "")
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pagamentos ( NomeFornecedor, NFatura, Data, Valor, IVA, Total, Situacao, MPagamento, Dataliquidacao, Obs) VALUES ( '" + comboBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "' , '" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();
            MessageBox.Show("Pagamento Inserido");
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: All your columns are character typed? Also your `Clone` seems unnecessary. You connected your command and connection like `cmd.Connection = cn;`? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: This worked fine mate, but it isnt now :/

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: But is that causing the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the bin/debug folder, there you will find a copy of the databasr file (with data in it)